# htaccess RewriteRule to https doesn't work combined with other rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set a few rules in my `.htaccess` to work in a specific way:

1. Specific page redirections:

   ```bash
   RewriteRule "^web/site/mais$" https://www.main.com/front/for-you/insurance/ [R=301,L]
   ```
2. Home redirection

   ```bash
   RewriteRule ^$  https://www.forexample.com.br/for-you/ [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^/$  https://www.forexample.com.br/for-you/ [R=301,L]
   ```
3. HTTP to HTTPS and add www to the rest (this is what doesn't work), i tried many things:

   ```bash
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```

Other way I tried forgotting the www rule (but doesn't work too):

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The only way I found to combine is writting the general `https` and `www` rule in the `httpd.conf` and the other rules into the `.htaccess`, but this way I get two or more 301 redirects, bad business for SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the same problema with all the directories or only with some?

Because if you have ProxyPass (as you said), maybe it send you the redirections directly to Tomcat, so maybe you need to specify the rules into the ssl.conf to read that rules before leave the ssl.conf. Try to write the last you wrote into the ssl.conf after the ProxyPass

Comment: Yes, i've a proxy pass for images, js and css, Writting the specific for www into the ssl.conf and into the htaccess and leting the httpd.conf only with the Proxy Pass for images, js and css, ir works for me. The rules i used was:
ssl.conf down the proxypass and down the .htaccess:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect some spacific pages to https, forexample, To redirect :

- http://example.com/page.html

to

- https://www.example.com/page.html

And

- http://example.com/page2.html

to
- https://www.example.com/page2.html

You may try the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(page|page2)\.html$ https://www.example.com/$1.html [L,R]
```

If you want to redirect the whole site from http to https, you can use the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on


 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: It works, but in many cases uses twoo redirections. The problem is that i've proxypass rules to the main folder, so these rules causes that the request goes directly to the tomcat. Fineally i've fixed (more or less) the problem adding the www rule on the ssl.conf, leting the httpd.conf empty of redirects and the others (like you say) in the htaccess. This way i get only one 301 redirection in every specific but twoo if a try to redirect from https without www (I dont Know if the explanation is clear but it works enough for the SEO crow)